# How Do I Create Facebook Tab on My Fan Page that links to a facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-group

I want to create a tab on my facebook page that links to my facebook group.  Go to the page https://www.facebook.com/bettyrockershow

I have created an app tab and you can see there is one for the "betty rock you life facebook group"  https://www.facebook.com/groups/bettyrockyourlife/

How do I set it so that it sends people to the facebook group when clicked?

Comment: have you tried any code ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add some Javascript redirect on the tab page itself.

```
<script language="javascript">
    top.location.href = "https://www.facebook.com/groups/bettyrockyourlife/"
</script>
```

Also, sometimes it's best from a UX standpoint to tell the user what is going on.  Like setting a timer of a few seconds on the JS and placing a message on the page telling the user that the page will be redirecting elsewhere.

Comment: Zach,  Do I add this to the header in the page... or can I just put in in the html editor of wordpress?

Comment: Actually, I figured it out.  Thanks a lot.